# UITableView and UITableViewCell Swift

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I am working with Swift and am having a problem loading saved data into UITableView custom cell. I have created a ViewController/ TableViewController and TableViewCell. The form data is saving and is displayed in console. The problem is, nothing gets returned when going back to TableView (My list). I have created labels in the custom cell and everything seems to be linked correctly, but nothing is being displayed.. Am I missing something?

Here is the code from my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    var cell:UITableViewCell?
    @IBOutlet var txtPTitle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtPDesc: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtSDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtEDate: UITextField!

    // Add our date picker keyboard on Project Start Date
    @IBAction func dp(sender: UITextField!) {

        var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {

        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy"
        txtSDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }

    @IBAction func dp2(sender: UITextField!) {

        var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker2:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    func handleDatePicker2(sender: UIDatePicker) {

        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy"
        txtEDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }

    var project: String = ""
    var desc: String = ""
    var sdate: String = ""
    var edate: String = ""

    var existingItem: NSManagedObject!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (existingItem != nil) {

            txtPTitle.text = project
            txtPDesc.text = desc
            txtSDate.text = sdate
            txtEDate.text = edate
        }

        //Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        txtPTitle.delegate = self
        txtPDesc.delegate = self
        txtSDate.delegate = self
        txtEDate.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        txtPDesc.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func savedTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        // Reference to our app delegate
        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

        // Reference moc
        let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ProjectTask", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)
        // Check if task exists
        if (existingItem != nil) {

            existingItem.setValue(txtPTitle.text as String, forKey: "project")
            existingItem.setValue(txtPDesc.text as String, forKey: "desc")
            existingItem.setValue(txtSDate.text as String, forKey: "sdate")
            existingItem.setValue(txtEDate.text as String, forKey: "edate")

        } else {

            // Create instance of our data model and initialize
            var newItem = Model(entity: en, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

            // Map our properties
            newItem.project = txtPTitle.text
            newItem.desc = txtPDesc.text
            newItem.sdate = txtSDate.text
            newItem.edate = txtEDate.text

            println(newItem)
        }

        // Save our context
        contxt.save(nil)

        // Navigate back to root view controller
        self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {

        // Navigate back to root view controller
        self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Here is the code from my TableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Register Our Custom Table Cell //
        self.tableView.registerClass(ProjectTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "projectlist")

         func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!  {
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("projectlist", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ProjectTableViewCell

            cell.projectLabel.text = "project"
            return cell
        }

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 0
    }
```

Here is the code from the TableViewCell

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ProjectTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var projectLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    @IBOutlet var descriptionLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    @IBOutlet var sdateLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    @IBOutlet var edateLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

I also have another for NSManagedObject

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Model)
class Model: NSManagedObject {

    //Properties feed of attributes on our database - Must match the database attributes
    @NSManaged var project: String
    @NSManaged var desc: String
    @NSManaged var sdate: String
    @NSManaged var edate: String
}
```

Is there something I am missing here? This is driving me crazy. I read that this should be added to the tableviewcell, but I keep getting error this error: tableviewcell does not implement its superclass's required members

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're registering the class -- you should only do that if you create the cell entirely in code (that is, the subviews are created programmatically). If you made the cell in the storyboard, don't register anything. If you made it in a xib, then register the nib. All those lines like,

```
@IBOutlet var projectLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
```

don't make sense. You're creating a new label with no frame, but I assume you already created theses labels in IB somewhere (since you're using IBOutlets). If you did create them in IB, then those lines should be like so,

```
@IBOutlet var projectLabel: UILabel!
```

Comment: They were created in IB.. So, I shouldn't be registering them as above?

Comment: @jelliott, no you shouldn't. Registering the class tells the table view where to get the cells (and its views) from, so you won't see any subviews you made in IB.

Comment: thats what I had originally, but still no luck.. I've gone through everything.

Comment: Did you change those lines I mentioned in my answer to what I show (without the "= UILabel()" )?

Comment: Yes, that is what I had originally and changed back to

@IBOutlet var projectLabel: UILabel!

Comment: I added println(cell.projectLabel) in the TableViewController and am not getting anything printed in console.. All that is showing in console is that the data entered on the form has been added to database.

Comment: That tells me that there is a communication problem between the ViewController and TableView. 

There are no errors being displayed and every element has been registered. I am stumped.

Comment: @jelliott, I just noticed that you're returning 0 for number of rows in section. You need to be returning some non-zero number there. Usually the count of the array that you use to populate the table.

Comment: When I change, the simulator crashes

_configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3302.3.1/UITableView.m:7328
2014-08-08 14:15:59.106 test[89669:1426997] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: @jelliott, did you give your cell the reuse identifier, "project list" in IB?

Comment: sure did... "projectlist"

now it is showing error here:
            cell.projectLabel.text = "projectLabel"

Comment: Ok.. Getting somewhere.. I commented out this line:
//self.tableView.registerClass(ProjectTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "projectlist")

and it is now returning my label titles with:
            cell.projectLabel.text = "project"
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = "desc"
            cell.sdateLabel.text = "sdate"
            cell.edateLabel.text = "edate"

at least it is showing something.. Now I have to get it to load the actual data..

Comment: @jelliott, wtf? That's what I told you to do in my answer and first comment. I thought you had already done that.

Comment: and I did that.. I then moved somethings around that has brought me to where I am now. I appreciate all your input and have been looking through everything.. For something this simple, it is giving a lot of headache. Could this be a bug?

Comment: @jelliott, could what be a bug? It sounds like you have it working now (at least for your test strings).

Comment: Got it going in the right direction. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your init in TableViewCell class with following -

```
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

Comment: thanks.. that fixed the error, but data is still not displayed in tableview. Saving data is working and is shown in console, but there is nothing showing for the cell. It's like it doesn't exist.

Comment: this is what I am getting returned in console:

`<NSManagedObject: 0x7fbac9cb18b0> (entity: ProjectTask; id: 0x7fbac9cb1910 <x-coredata:///ProjectTask/t3C0EF636-7593-4B3F-B24A-3BB022BE702A2> ; data: {
    desc = dfdf;
    edate = "Jul 08 2014";
    project = dsfdf;
    sdate = "Jun 08 2014";
})`

Comment: Have u checked for the delegate and datasource of table view in storyboard?

Comment: Yes. TableView has both delegate and datasource set. When removing the custom cell, everything works fine.

Comment: I can send a zip, if needed.